# Loop through json decoded array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I have data in Json format which i have decoded into a php array which when printed produces the following (just a snippet of the information).

```
Array (
[Title] => Array([Heading] => Company Name [Info] =>)
[SubTitle] => Array([Heading] => Welcome to Company Name[Info] =>information on the company)
)
```

my question is how do I loop through this information and print the title and then print the value.

I have tried the following which prints all the data at one time

```
  foreach($data['SubTitle'] as $key => $value){

    echo $value;
   }
```

And then i tried this just to print the info section which i thought might work but instead throws an illegal string offset error

```
   foreach($data['SubTitle'] as $key => $v){

    echo $v['Info'];
   }
```

I can get the information from the Title array as it is straight forward as it only has data value in the heading. However i would like the output from the Subtitle array to print the heading and info like below:

Welcome to Company Name

Information on the company

I thought this would be straight forward but it is turning out much more difficult than expected and has taken up a lot of time so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question and write exactly what you want the output to be. Depending on the array you entered.

Comment: `echo $v;` will be enough

Comment: I have editied my question to show what output i hope to achieve. Many Thanks in advance if you can provide any help

Comment: @catcon i have tried echo v and it prints all the information in one output but i require the information to be seperate

Comment: It does not print all in one output, it goes through each item and `echo` each item separately. You need to separate the information, you can do it by adding space/new line/wrap it with div/etc. i.e: `echo "<div>$v</div>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am going to assume you have a JSON string that looks like this:

```
$json = '{"Title":{"Heading": "Company Name", "Info": null}, "SubTitle": {"Heading": "Welcome to Company Name", "Info": "information on the company"}}';
```

visualised, looks something like this:

[image]

So, if you've decoded this json into an associative array:

```
$result = json_decode($json, true);
```

Then, in order to access the data, you don't need to "loop" over it; all you need to do is:

```
echo $result['Title']['Heading']; // will print 'Company Name'
echo $result['Title']['Info']; // will print nothing, as it is empty
echo $result['SubTitle']['Heading']; // will print 'Welcome to Company Name'
echo $result['SubTitle']['Info']; // will print 'information on the company'
```

Hope this helps. This is basic php, please look into the following reading materials:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php
- https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp

Answer (score 0):

Change your code, from this:

```
foreach($data['SubTitle'] as $key => $v){
    echo $v['Info'];
}
```

To this:

```
foreach($data['SubTitle'] as $v){
    echo $v . "<br/>"; // the <br/> makes a new line
}
```

Output will be:

```
Welcome to Company Name
Information on the company
```

**$v** is no longer an array in foreach, it becomes a variable.

Some information about html tags: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/

Also see how loop works: https://www.guru99.com/php-loop.html